# How to update rows in a database without overwriting previous data

Tags: sql-update

I have a database table that I store patient information in, along with files such as images and Word documents. when updating this table, it overwrites previous data stored. How do I prevent this from happening?

Comment: If you mean within an SQL 'UPDATE' statement, just use "UPDATE table SET field_i_want_to_update = newvalue;"; and not "set" fields you don't want overwritten. If your trying to preserve the entire record, than you'd want to INSERT a new record for that patient (with a new unique key, like PATIENT_NUM + SEQ_NUM).

Comment: Basically i'm pulling information from a form then update the info in the database with info taken from the form. using the update statement

Comment: `UPDATE` does just that: it updates the existing data with new content. IOW, it's **designed** to overwrite previous data in a column with new data. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Say for instance i update a specific field i don't want it to overwrite the previous info that was there.

Answer (score 1):

According to your comment , first you need to backup the old values into other table with same columns data type :

```
insert into backup_table ( column1 , column2 , ... )
SELECT  column1 , column2 , ...
FROM    orginal_table
```

then update statement should look like this :

```
UPDATE orginal_table
SET column1=form_value1, column2=form_value2 ,...
WHERE some_column=some_value
```

Comment: is it possible to add another row with the updated info in the same table?

Comment: It depends on your table design and relations with other tables.

Comment: patients table has n foreign key in it